# Need Help Getting Responsive Design on Header Image

Tags: html, css

my whole website is responsive except from my banner/header and I can't seem to find a fix for it. I use viewport for responsiveness and my banner does not react to it at all!

Here is a simple JSFiddle of the header, 
https://jsfiddle.net/Syystole/L9r2p9so/19/

HTML

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


<div class="WrapperPage">
        <div id="banner"></div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.WrapperPage {
    max-width:62em;
    margin:auto;
            }

#banner {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1"); <!./ starts from current directory>
    text-align:center;
    padding:170px;
        }
```

Comment: Seems like you want to use `background-size: cover` but not sure. What do you mean when you say you want it to be responsive? How do you want it to behave exactly when the viewport is resized?

Comment: just want to see the whole image in a smaller view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the whole image to be visible and scale with the viewport, use a combination of `background-size: cover` to stretch the image to fit the element, and `padding-bottom: 50%` to match the aspect ratio of the image so that there is always room for the entire image to be shown

```css
.WrapperPage {
  max-width: 62em;
  margin: auto;
}

#banner {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1");
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="WrapperPage">
  <div id="banner"></div>
  <p>
    body text
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Syystole be more specific. What doesn't work? What are you looking for?

Comment: @Syystole you said "just want to see the whole image in a smaller view." This enables you to see the whole image in a smaller view, or any view.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/bXPEiBC.jpg this is what happens on my page for some reason when I use this code

Comment: @Syystole I can't help you with a screenshot. It's your responsibility to provide the code needed to reproduce the problem, and we solve the problem in your post - not on your personal website. What am I supposed to do with a screenshot?